# Is it possible to use foreign keys with NULL values?

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys

I know that similar questions were asked before, but still not clear for me.

I have a table called “cities” and a table called “profiles”. The city is an optional field to be entered by the user on the table “profiles”. So fk_id_city might be NULL.

1) What is the best practice to manage this situation if foreign key wants to be used? (Some people suggested me not to use FK in these cases).

2) One idea that occur to me is to have the first row of the table “cities” as “to be defined” so if the user doesn’t select any city from the form, instead of having a NULL field I will have a “1”. Would you suggest this?

E.G.

Table cities

> ```
> id_city (pk)      city_name 
> ---------------------------------
> 1                 to be defined
> 2                 New York
> 3                 London 
> 4                 Buenos Aires
> ```

Table profiles

> ```
> id_profile (pk)      Name         fk_id_city 
> ----------------------------------------
> 1                    Paul            2       
> 2                    John            1 
> 3                    Paul            1
> ```

**Additional info:**
If I try to leave the fk_id_city empty, I get the following error: ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (db/profile, CONSTRAINT fk_id_city FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_city) REFERENCES cities (id_city) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve, exactly? What is the problem with leaving the FK NULL?

Comment: If I try to leave the fk_id_city empty, I get the following error: ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gpj/profile`, CONSTRAINT `fk_id_city` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_id_city`) REFERENCES `cities` (`id_city`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: Well, don't leave it empty. Leave it NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In standard SQL, columns with a FOREIGN KEY constraint defined on them will permit nulls even where there is no corresponding null in the table being referenced. Nulls are permitted if you choose to allow them by not specifying NOT NULL in the column definition. There are multiple issues with this however. Not all DBMSs follow the ISO standard and so the behaviour can differ between different products. Some applications and development tools may also treat nullable constraints in ways that are inconsistent with your DBMS. Database users probably won't understand what a nullable foreign key means or know what behaviours to expect - for example many people might write an inner join between a foreign key column and the column it references and expect all the rows to be returned, but that won't be the case if some of the values are null.

So think about what a nullable foreign key means *logically* in your data model. Why do you want to populate nulls when no city has been defined? A simple alternative in your case would be to create a new table with non-nullable columns `id_profile` and `fk_id_city`. Only populate that table when you have a city defined.

Comment: So you think is better to create a 3° table with non-nullable columns id_profile and fk_id_city rather than having only 2 tables with nulls? What is the criteria to decide to create an extra table?

Comment: Logically, a NULL in a foreign key corresponds to an optional relationship,  a relationship in which the entity may participate zero or one times.  That being the case, one would expect a row containing a NULL to drop out of the inner join.

Comment: The criterium is whenever your inclination is to introduce a nullable column, don't.

Comment: The sad thing is that all the DBMS vendors actively punish you in the performance arena for doing things the logically correct way.

Comment: @ErwinSmout Care to elaborate? In many cases, a NULL foreign key seems like a perfectly valid design choice.

Comment: Surprised to see you ask the question, I must say.  They are often a valid design choice _because_ you must ultimately avoid the performance penalty your SQL DBMS vendor imposes on you for doing things the logically correct way.  There's a section on NULL and 3VL in Darwen's "Introduction to relational theory" and also in several of Date's books, e.g. "Logic and Databases" ('why database logic must be 2-valued').  Outside of the specific database context, C.A.R. Hoare is on record calling his invention of the "null reference" his billion-dollar mistake.

Comment: @ErwinSmout My background is in a different literature (they are mostly Serbian authors you probably are not familiar with) and I haven't read the books you mentioned. So could you please "compress" is for me here - how exactly would you replace NULL-able foreign key with a NOT NULL? Or at least point to the specific book section that I can find straight away?

Comment: Darwen also has a presentation on the matter at http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/Missing-info-without-nulls.pdf .  NULL has been the subject of the most heated of debates for decades in a row, so asking to "compress" it all in a comment here really is a tall order !  The "proposed solution" in the pdf is logically sound and 100% in agreement with the RM, "pure version", however it will take a couple of things to get there : e.g. fix the current integrity support currently offered by SQL engines (way too limited these days)

Comment: @ErwinSmout OK, the best I could gather from the presentation is that a NULL-able foreign key should be extracted into its own table. How exactly is that "better"? I understand the NULLs are a bit of a hack and not all that consistent, which mostly stems from clamping the concept of "value" (or lack thereof) with the concept of "comparison" (in contrast, see how comparison is factored-out in .NET BCL or C++ STL), but at least for foreign keys, NULL represents a specific, well-defined thing.